# The chance that the rod AB will be of atleast 1 m in length?

Tags: probability

A wooden rod is 6m long.It is cut at random at two places A and B on the two sides to obtain a smaller rod AB.What is the chance that the rod AB will be of atleast 1 m in length?

Probability of length AB to be atleast 1 m is $1-$ probability that length AB is not 1 m.But how do we find that.I am stuck here.Its answer given is $\frac{25}{36}$.I can only guess,i have no concrete logic,how this came.Please guide me.

Comment: Is there any additional data , like probability distribution by which cuts are made ?

Comment: Only this much information is given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map out the probability space on the Cartesian plane using X axis to plot the position of A, and Y axis to plot the position of B. The possibilities cover a square 6x6 (total area of 36).

Find areas on the map where A and B are within 1m of each other (ie $|y-x|<1$). This will form a band along the diagonal bounded by $y=x+1$ and $y=x-1$.

The required probability is the proportion of the square outside this band. This will consist of two right angled triangles each of base 5 and height 5 for a total area (for the two triangles) of 25.

So your probability of A and B being more than 1m apart (giving you a rod of length 1m) is $\frac{25}{36}$.

Note that we are assuming (unstated explicitly in your question) that A and B are independent variables distributed uniformly over (0, 1). This allows us to picture the probability space as a two dimensional map.